# React update input text value using state and make it mutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to change input text value using state and React `value` property and also make the field editable.

My component's constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // States
    this.state = {
        value: this.props.object.subtext
    };

    this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

My `render()` function:

```
return (
    <input
        type={this.props.object.type}
        value={this.props.object.subtext}
        onChange={this._handleChange}
    />
);
```

`componentDidUpdate()` function:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.value !== this.props.object.subtext) {
        this.setState({value: this.props.object.subtext});
    }
}
```

And for `_handleChange(e)` function:

```
_handleChange(e) {
    this.props.object.subtext = e.target.value;
    this.componentDidUpdate(); // not sure it's right or not
}
```

The code works fine, but I'm a little bit unsure that was the best practice or not because I recalled `this.componentDidUpdate()` manually inside the event handler function.

I did it to fix my previous bug which is the value of input component won't be updated when the state was changed.

I want to know whether what I'm doing is right or not, any comments or answers will be appreciated.

Comment: do not change props inside component. _handleChange should pass value to the parent component callback

Answer (score 2):

No its not a good practise to call the lifecycle function yourself

Rather than that, you can modify your state props like

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // States
    this.state = {
        value: this.props.object.subtext
    };

    this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this);
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.object.subtext !== nextProps.object.subtext) {
        this.setState({value: nextProps.object.subtext});
    }
}
_handleChange(e) {

    //cal a parent compoent function
    this.props.changeProps(e.target.value);
}
```

Comment: Where's the `this.props.changeProps()` come from?

Comment: Define a function changeProps in the parent component which changes the value object.subtext passed down to child and pass this function to you child functin like  <Child changeProps={(val)=> {this.changeProps(val)}} />

Comment: But, the input component become immutable now.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it and `this.props.object.subtext = e.target.value;`, is wrong,

Comment: Does `this.props.object.subtext = e.target.value;` make it become immutable?

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected calling `componentDidUpdate` is bad idea. You can change your state in `_handleChange` and remove `componentDidUpdate` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can `setState` in `_handleChange`. You'll need to bind to `this.state.value` for your local state, though, opposed to `this.props.object.subtext`. Observe the following...

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    value: this.props.object.subtext
  };
}

_handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({
    value: e.target.value
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <input
      type={this.props.object.type}
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this._handleChange.bind(this)}
    />
  );
}
```

Alternatively, if you're looking for a `props` only solution without local state, I suggest giving [redux](http://redux.js.org/)
 a look.

Comment: I tried this, but the input text value was not updated when state was changed.

Comment: Should work just fine. Granted, while not TypeScript or a class, here is a working sample exactly replicated - [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/uogfL8d2/)